# Symmetric closure in a topological space

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Consider the following property of a (typically not $T_1$) topological space $X$: given any $x_1,x_2\in X$, we have that $x_1\in \overline{\{x_2\}}$ if and only if $x_2\in \overline{\{x_1\}}$.

It's equivalent to saying that closures of points are minimal closed sets.

Does this property have a name?

Comment: Yes, topological indistinguishability: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_indistinguishability

Comment: One phrasing (not name) for this property would be "space whose specialization preorder is an equivalence relation".

Comment: In fact, the Wikipedia page for specialization preorder refers to your type of space as an "$R_0$ space" (seemly analogous naming to $T_0$ or $T_1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of space is apparently called an $R_0$ space; this terminology is backed up by

- The [Wikipedia page for Specialization (pre)order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specialization_(pre)order).
- The [Wikipedia page for $T_1$ spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space).
- [This article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311809333_On_R0_Space_in_L-Topological_Spaces) found by googling "$R_0$ space".

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.