# $R_0$ space with Hausdorff quotient

Tags: general-topology, terminology, separation-axioms

This is a follow-up to [a previous question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2773567/30222).

If $X$ is an $R_0$ space (see the linked question), then the quotient obtained by identifying two points if their closures are equal is $T_1$ (in fact, it is the universal $T_1$ quotient of $X$, and this property is equivalent to being $R_0$).

Let us say that $X$ is an $R_1$ space if this quotient is actually Hausdorff.

For example, any topological group is an $R_1$-space.

Does this $R_1$ property have a standard name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $R_1$, or *preregular*, is the standard name it seems: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space), it explicitly mentions that a space is $R_1$ iff its Kolmogorov quotient (identifying topologically indistinguishable points) is $T_2$. So a space is $R_i$ iff its Kolmogorov quotient is $T_{i+1}$ holds for $i=0$ and $i=1$.

A space is $T_2$ (Hausdorff) iff it is both $R_1$ and $T_0$. I have seen $R_0$ and $R_1$ used in some papers (in the context of uniform spaces, e.g.), but preregular not so much.

Comment: Once more I missed something available on Wikipedia. Now that's embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, do you know about $R_i$ spaces for $i>1$? It would seem natural to define them at least for $i=2,2\frac12,3,4,5$, but I haven't even encountered $R_0$ or $R_1$ before.

Comment: @tomasz no, I believe only those 2 are in use.